# Two different JPEGs file size (from different software) size after exporting same png

Tags: image, image-processing, png, jpeg

I have a png non compressed file (600kbytes) that I am trying to save as JPG, in order to reduce the size of an android app.

1. When I use photoshop CS6 to export the file as JPG size is around
   300Kbytes with max quality
2. When I use BulkImageConverter software to
   batch convert several files, the file generated has the same maximum
   quality as the one exported by photoshop but its size is 50Kbytes.

I couldn't find any difference between the two images (even in quality), except in the image properties :

- Photoshop image has "Resolution Unit" :2 / "Color Representation" : Uncalibrated
- BulkImageConverter image has nothing for those two fields

This is happening on all images, not a specific one.

Is this additional data causing the size of the photoshop image exported as JPEG to have an additional size? Is there any risk using that low size JPEG image in android app, what is actually being compressed/left out?

kindly let me know if any additional detail is needed.

Thank you.

Comment: "300Kbytes with max quality" Well, just try with lower quality

Comment: When exporting your JPEG from CS6, did you "Save as..." or "Export for Web..." (or what the respective actions are called these days)? "Save as..." will probably contain a lot of meta data, color profile, thumbnail, etc that "Export for web" will leave out. "Export for web" should be closer to BulkImageConverter in size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to guess just from the descriptions. First, PNG images are compressed. It's lossless compression and it's the same as JPEG uses in the end. Second, JPEG has two quality settings:

- Chroma subsampling - basically how many pixels will share color information
- Quantization - how much of the details is lost

There is nothing like a single "quality setting" in JPEG. Every software simply converts the one number to some subsampling and some quantization. Even if two graphics softwares say 100%, it can mean different thing.

You can use software like [JPEGSnoop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpegsnoop/) to analyze the quality. What is happening in your case is most likely the chroma subsampling difference. There will be little to none quantization in both cases, but Photoshop uses the best subsampling (none) starting with the quality setting 7. I do not know the other software, but it is likely using lower quality subsampling.

Usually the subsampling is written as 4:2:2, 4:1:1, [see the explanation on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling). JPEGSnoop uses the following notation:

- `Chroma subsampling:  2x2` - this means 2x2 square shares the same color and it is the most common JPEG setting.
- `Chroma subsampling:  1x1` - basically no subsampling, Photoshop does that for high quality.

Check this in your exported images.

---

> Is this additional data causing the size of the photoshop image exported as JPEG to have an additional size?

Well, yes and no. The text itself has little effect, but photoshop tells you that the color information is uncalibrated - probably meaning less compression, less optimization.

> Is there any risk using that low size JPEG image in android app, what is actually being compressed/left out?

No, Android can decode most of the JPEGs there are. The quality might be lower and it could be maybe noticed on a big screen with perfect color calibration and high contrast.

Comment: (Remark.) Explanations for the subsampling notation can be found on Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling

Comment: @rwong Thanks, I added it ot the answer, it might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that Photoshop can sometimes add an appreciable amount of metadata to images, including colour profiles, thumbnail images and EXIF data. However, the main reason for the difference in file sizes is likely to be differences in the way JPEG compression is implemented between these two applications.

In general, you should store images in a non-lossy format like TIFF or PNG while you're working on them. When exporting to JPEG, a compression level of around 60–80% is usually quite adequate. Sometimes it helps to apply a "sharpen edges" filter before compression.

There's no risk of using higher compression levels in android apps or anywhere else. If an image looks fine, then it's fine.

Comment: Colour profiles and EXIF data would hardly add more than 5K. See http://www.controlledvocabulary.com/blog/top-metadata-myths.html

Comment: Random example... running ImageMagick's `mogrify -strip` command on [this image](http://www.stbudeauxtennisclub.co.uk/images/Gallery/DSCF9249.jpg) removes 11552 bytes of data without altering a single pixel. But you have a point; I'll tone down the hyperbole a bit :-)

Comment: @leonbloy: That really depends... ICC color profiles may be several MB in size and split into multiple `ICC_PROFILE` segments (but these are rare, I'll give you that). Also, Adobe usually adds an XMP metadat block (which extra spaces to allow for inline editing) in addition to EXIF. Your milage may vary.